# Upload videos to youtube without having the user sign in

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, google-signin

I want to create a web application that allows the users to upload videos to a specific YouTube account. The users do not have gmail accounts and they have to access YouTube via one login. Is there a way for me to achieve this without having the users to login to the Google account.

I have tried the samples provided by the [YouTube API](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples). These first show the Google+ log in screen for the users to enter the credentials. What i want, is for the application to login, without the users knowing it. Is it possible to implement a way for the application to signin to the account without its users realizing it. Please provide me with a soution. So far I have tried the YouTube JavaScript API.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: YouTube is not accessible without a google account anymore, therefore you have just answered your own question. `The users do not have gmail accounts`. On the other hand, `they have to access YouTube via one login`, means you already ask them to connect into your app, so why not `connect with google` and ask for the youtube api permission there.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube is dependent on gmail emails now. They switched a while back.

You should be able to have them login once, and then your application could remember their login.

YouTube's authentication is going to need them to login so the OAuth token can be handed off.

Comment: thank you for the response. i dont want the users to be given the credentials for the YouTube account. They just need to upload the video through my application without having to login. Is there a way to authenticate my application and not have each user login? maybe there is a functionality available in YouTube that i am not aware of?

Comment: Knowing there must be a owner of the video as you cannot upload anonymous videos, you could simply upload the video using your API credentials and your channel. Just name the video like `username | video title`.

Comment: @Eduard is right. Since you can't upload anonymous videos, you could have them upload it through your application, but it would basically be the same as logging in as you, and posting the video. Your app would be the owner of the videos. Just curious, who would anonymously post videos?